# Cannot Set HTTP Cookie in Browser From Spring Boot Application

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, httpcookie

```
public static Cookie createCookie(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {

Cookie cookie = new Cookie("XYZ-Cookie", "12345");
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
cookie.setMaxAge(60*30*1000);
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setComment("HTTP Cookie");

httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie);

}

}
```

I have tried to Set HTTP Cookie from Spring Boot Application to the browser. The Cookie is set in response but cookie is not set in browser while react application request any API to the spring boot application.

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue, did you manage to solve it ?